# Xcode New Build System CocoaPods "Copy Pods Resources" has Assets.car in Output Files and conflict with "Copy Bundle Resources"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

We are using new build system and Cocoapods 1.7.5 for our Xcode project. Our project (let's call it Y) is actually a development pod, but we also have written some codes to create an application demo (you know, to make builds faster and iterations quicker). These demo codes (`AppDelegate.swift`, launch tasks etc.) are not included in the development pod. The remaining ~90 percent of the source codes and resource files (such as i18n strings and image resources) get packed into the development pod for another project (let's call it X) to use.

While developing, most of the changes occur to the dev pod part of Y, so we need to make sure that every slice of change is included when X does `pod install`.

Recently we encountered a problem:

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/x/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Y-cawteybtitmeiafweribgqzkuhnr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Y.app/Assets.car':
1) Target 'Y' (project 'Y') has compile command with input '/Users/name/DEV/workspace/Y/SupportFiles/Assets.xcassets'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Y' (project 'Y'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

After hours of searching `multiple commands produce assets.car` on Google, we finally saw a plausible [explanation](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8122#issuecomment-427237139):

> *.xcassets of Copy Bundle Resources --> Assets.car
>
> *.xcassets of [CP] Copy Pods Resource --> other Assets.car
>
> The first one covers second in the New Build System，That's the reason.

When we manually remove the `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Assets.car` from output files of `[CP] Copy Pods Resource`, the error is gone and everything works fine. However, whenever we `git checkout` to another branch, or `pod install`, or `pod update`, there is a pretty high chance that the `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Assets.car` appears again in the output files of `[CP] Copy Pods Resource`. We need to manually remove it again and again, which is tedious and frustrating.

Then we started to question: Who is behind all this? Who is responsible for adding `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Assets.car` to the output files of `[CP] Copy Pods Resource`? We focused our sight onto `Y.podspec` and found these lines:

```
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'Y' => ['Resources/*'], # assets, lottie etc.
    'YAuto' => ['auto_resources/*'] # i18n strings etc.
  }
```

We thought we were using `resource_bundles` wrong, so we looked it up, again on Google. Surprisingly, using `resource_bundles` over `resources` is recommended by [official documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles). Additionally, we couldn't find any inappropriate usage in terms of `resource_bundles`, leaving us out of options.

Can somebody help? I was thinking maybe we could patch `Y.xcworkspace` in the `post_install` script in `Podfile`, but I don't know how.

Comment: maybe related to https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8431

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions proposed in your link has successfully addressed my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Related post with some workarounds: https://dev.to/kylefoo/xcode-12-new-build-system-warns-multiple-commands-produce-assets-car-56im

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been nearly a month and here is an update. Turned out that this problem was caused by a misuse of another development pod of `Y`. We forgot to use `resource_bundles` in the `Podspec` of that dev pod, which leaded to the resources of that dev pod NOT been packed into a `.bundle` file, followed by `[CP] Copy Pods Resources` explicitly adding an `xcassets` into the input files, colliding with the other one in the `Copy Bundle Resources`.

Comment: hi using `resouce_bundles` i can not retrieve image assets with Xcode 12.5. There is always `Assets.car`in Pod.bundle, can not retrieve image assets

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by writing a `post_install` script in `Podfile` which automatically deletes these `Assets.car`.

```
post_install do |installer|
    project_path = 'Y.xcodeproj'
    project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
    project.targets.each do |target|
        build_phase = target.build_phases.find { |bp| bp.display_name == '[CP] Copy Pods Resources' }
        assets_path = '${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Assets.car'
        if build_phase.present? && build_phase.output_paths.include?(assets_path) == true
            build_phase.output_paths.delete(assets_path)
        end
    end
    project.save(project_path)
end
```

It seems to be a CocoaPods bug that still has not been fixed by now.

Comment: Got `undefined method 'include'? for nil:NilClass` for `build_phase.output_paths.include?`

Comment: You may need to add `require 'xcodeproj'` to the top of your Podfile

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clarification. I actually solved it by just running `pod update`. The problem probably lied in an older version of one of the many frameworks we're using.

Answer (score 4):

This issue comes about in many ways; some like the described problem above and other times for having a Share Extension or Watch app in addition to an iOS app. In all scenarios, it's caused by there being multiple `Assets.car` outputs in the `[CP] Copy Pods Resources` of those targets which create duplicate `Assets.car` files. The compiler obviously doesn't know how to handle that, so we shouldn't be allowing CocoaPods to generate multiple output files with the same name.

The recommended solution per [the CocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8122) is to put this in your `Podfile`:

```rb
# Default platform for most targets
platform :ios, '11.0'

# Workaround duplicate Assets.car issue https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8122
# This impacts the new Xcode build system
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true
```

Xcode 12 also fixes an accompanying issue that let to build performance issues when using the new build system with this workaround. The legacy build system is officially deprecated as of Xcode 12.

Comment: After spending 4 hours this, this was the answer and fixed the issue.. Thank you.